# Error 500 when accessing jsp resource using maven unit test

Tags: eclipse, jsp, unit-testing, maven, jetty

I get 500 error when trying to access a jsp through unit tests, the unit test is working perfectly fine in eclipse, however, it errors out with 500 code when ran through maven.

I used:

```
mvn clean package -> which runs all the unit tests
```

Sample code:

```
    // Starting a jetty server
    jettyServer.start();
    ....
    // URL to the page the test wanted to validate
    URL url = new URL(getUrl() + "/Stats.jsp");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    try {
       conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
       conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml");
    ....
    // FAILING HERE WITH 500
    assertEquals("Didn't get a succesful http response, output: " + conn.getResponseMessage(), 200, conn.getResponseCode());
```

The jsp is located under:
src/main/resources/jsp

I tried to add mvn dependencies for all the jetty-related jar files that are under "Reference Libraries", and they are now under "Maven Dependencies" as well, but, that doesn't seem to help much.

Later in the logs I see some interesting warning not sure if it's related or not:

```
2015-05-24 14:35:08,362 WARN  [qtp82416174-739] servlet.ServletHandler(620):
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil.expandClassPath(Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List;
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:400)
at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.service(JettyJspServlet.java:103)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil.expandClassPath(Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List;
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Jsr199JavaCompiler.setClassPath(Jsr199JavaCompiler.java:123)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:348)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
```

Any idea what could be wrong? did i miss anything with the jsp setup or is there anything special needs to happen in mvn configurations to let jetty server able to serve the jsp?

Thanks for your help!